# Is cardinality of $S$ finite or infinite?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is statement true or false?

Let $A = \{1,2,3, \ldots, 10\}$. $S$ is subset of $A$. $|S|$ denotes the number of elements in $S$. Then $$\sum_{S\subset A,S\ne \emptyset}^\ {(-1)^{|S|}} =10$$ 
my attempt:  here $|S| =10$ so $ (-1)^{10} = 1$

Now i add this $\underbrace{1+1+ \cdots +1}_{10 \text{ times}} = 10$ so im getting  $$\sum_{S\subset A,S\ne \emptyset}^\ {(-1)^{|S|}} =10$$

Is my answer is correct or not pliz verified and tell me the solution....

Comment: No, $S$ runs over the $1023$ non-empty subsets of $A$. Some of these subsets have an even number of elements, and some have an odd number of elements.

Comment: $S$ does not always have ten elements. $S$ is a subset of $A$, and $A$ is the set with $10$ elements. You sum over all $S\subset A$, $S\neq\emptyset$.

Comment: im not getting @ Hagen VonEitzen,,how ithe cardinilaity come 1023

Comment: The sum isn't $1023$ however there are $1023$ terms in the sum.  Some of these $1023$ terms are equal to one and the rest are equal to negative one.  It is $1023$ because it is well known that the number of subsets total of a set with $n$ elements is $2^n$, and if you exclude the empty set then you subtract one from that.  Here, $2^{10}-1=1023$

Comment: Expanding the summation a bit more so you can see what is happening, the summation ranges over all nonempty subsets of $A$, so we are adding $(-1)^{|\{1\}|}+(-1)^{|\{1,2\}|}+(-1)^{|\{1,2,3\}|}+\dots+(-1)^{|\{2\}|}+(-1)^{|\{2,3\}|}+\dots+(-1)^{|\{1,2,\dots,10\}|}$

Comment: thanks a lots @JMoravitz..

Comment: As an aside, if all you are interested in is whether or not the statement is true or false, even without knowing what the sum actually is so long as you understand why there are $1023$ terms in the sum you know immediately that the statement is false since an odd number of odd summands will add up to be an odd number, never an even number.

Answer (score 2):

$A$ has exactly $2^9$ subsets of even cardinality and $2^9$ subsets of odd cardinality. Thus, the sum consists of $2^9 - 1$ positive ones (we have to exclude $\emptyset$) and $2^9$ negative ones:

$$\sum_{S\subset A, S \ne \emptyset} (-1)^{|S|} = (2^9 - 1) - 2^9 = -1$$

---

To prove that the set $\{1, \ldots, n\}$ has the same number of subsets of even cardinality and odd cardinality, you can check that the function $A \mapsto A \,\Delta\,\{n\}$ for $A \subseteq \{1, \ldots, n\}$ bijectively maps even subsets to odd subsets and vice-versa. The total number of subsets is $2^n$, so there are $2^{n-1}$ even and odd subsets.

Comment: @ mechanodroid $ |S| = 2^{9} -1  + 2^{9} $...i not getting how summation comes -1

Comment: @lomberlego It is $$(2^9 - 1) \cdot (-1)^\text{even number} + 2^9 \cdot (-1)^\text{odd number} = 2^9 - 1 - 2^9 = -1$$

Comment: ok  ,,thanks a lot @mechanodroid

Answer (score 1):

The number of subsets $S$ of $A=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$ such that $|S|=k$, for $0\leq k\leq 10 $, is 
$$
\binom{10}{k}=\frac{10!}{k!(10-k)!}
$$
Then 
$$
\sum_{S\subset A} (-1)^{|S|}
=
\sum_{k=0}^{10}\sum_{|S|=k} (-1)^{|S|}
=
\sum_{k=0}^{10}\binom{10}{k}(-1)^{k}
$$
By binomial theorem 
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{10}\binom{10}{k}(-1)^{k}
=
\sum_{k=0}^{10}\binom{10}{k}(-1)^{k}(+1)^{10-k}
=
(-1+1)^{10}
=0
$$
Here, $\sum_{|S|=0}(-1)^{|S|}=(-1)^{|\emptyset|}=(-1)^{0}=1$. Then

$$
\sum_{S\subset A, S\neq\emptyset} (-1)^{|S|}= \sum_{S\subset A} (-1)^{|S|}-\sum_{|S|=0}(-1)^{|S|}=0-1=-1
$$

Comment: And then take into account that the empty set is excluded from the original sum.

Comment: @Mathoverview ,,,,according to mechanodroid    answer is  -1.....im confused which answer is correct

Comment: Yes, the answer is $-1$. May answer is too $-1$.